# foreach() invalid argument error using jquery and ajax error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this input fields,

```
<input type="text" name="member[]" class="memberName" value="$member_name"/>
<input  type="text" name="position[]" value="$position">
<input value="Male" name="gender[]" type="radio" class="Gender" />
<input value="Female" name="gender[]" type="radio" class="Gender" />
```

And I'm using jquery and ajax to get the values,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var member_name = [];
    $('.memberName').each(function(){  
            if($(this).is(":checked"))  
            {  
                 member_name.push($(this).val());  
            }  
       });  
       member_name = member_name.toString();  
       console.log(member_name);

    var member_position = [];
    $('.memberPosition').each(function(){  
            if($(this).is(":checked"))  
            {  
                 member_position.push($(this).val());  
            }  
       });  
       member_position = member_position.toString(); 

    var gender = [];
    $('.Gender').each(function(){  
            if($(this).is(":checked"))  
            {  
                 gender.push($(this).val());  
            }  
       });  
       gender = gender.toString();
$.ajax({
url: "Queries/save.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"member_name":member_name, "member_position":member_position, 
          "gender":gender
},
        success: function(yey){
          console.log(yey);
          alert(yey);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

And this my save.php,

```
if(isset($_POST['member_name']) || isset($_POST['member_position']) || isset($_POST['gender']) || isset($_POST['user_id'])){
$member_name = $_POST['member_name'];
$position = $_POST['member_position'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$IDuser = $_POST['user_id'];
foreach($member_name as $mname) {

    $position = $_POST['member_position'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    $compos_date = $_POST['cmatcompos_date'];

    $sql_check = "SELECT ID_cmat FROM cmat_composition WHERE ID_users = '$IDuser' AND Saved = '1' 
    AND cmatcompos_date = '$compos_date'";
    $result_check = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_check); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_check);
    $ID_cmat = $row['ID_cmat'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO members (member_name, position, gender, total_male, total_female, Saved, ID_cmat, ID_users)

    VALUES  ('$mname', '$position', '$gender', '1', '$ID_cmat', '$IDuser')";  

    $success = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);      
}
}
```

I have declared the variables into array in jquery but why am I still having the Invalid argument supplied in foreach() error? Any idea? Please help. I'm still new at jquery and ajax. Thank you.

Comment: What does $member_name look like? The reason for the error is that it is not an array. You will probably have to explode(",",$member_name)

Comment: That value is base on my select query and I have this $member_name = $row['member_name']; to get that row and put it on that input field value.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your line of JavaScript code `member_name = member_name.toString();`. When `member_name` gets sent over to the server, it's still a string, and you're attempting to iterate on that string when you really want to iterate on it as an array.

If you want to log the array in JavaScript before sending it over to the server, then delete that line and instead of `console.log(member_name);` do `console.log(member_name.toString());`.

Comment: I have tried that sir and it says Undefined member_name.